# A Cryptic Property

Tags: pattern, word-property, cryptic-clues, connections-puzzle

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #48: Unusual tag mix](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/fortnightly-topic-challenge-48-unusual-tag-mix)</sup>

---

After solving the following cryptic clues, find the following properties:

1. A major property that all ten words share.
2. A minor property shared by the words in one set, but not the other.

### Group 1

1. Round, crooked grin (4)
2. Half-baked trifles accomodating upper class's return (5)
3. Contact the old university heads before church (5)
4. Mean queen following Penny (6)
5. Floating motion around two different motorways (8)

### Group 2

1. Youthful graduate at hand (4)
2. Wandering nomad meets unknown from beginning of week (6)
3. Crowds in somber assembly back peacekeepers instead of nothing (7)
4. Lower poles around distant, enclosing gas (8)
5. Sour, ripe bananas from manager (8)

Comment: I think I can get 9/10 clues but the connections are quite tricky.

Comment: @hexomino The connections are a bit different than what is normally seen in the Word/Phrase puzzles, but I think (hope) this tag still applies. The second property also depends on the first property, if that helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Clues – Group 1

> **Round**, crooked grin (4)
>    — **RING** = GRIN* ("crooked")
>
>  Half-baked trifles accomodating upper class's **return** (5)
>    — **FRUIT** = U (upper class) in (TRIF(les))* ("half-baked", or 4/7-"baked", more like)
>
>  **Contact** the old university heads before church (5)
>    — **TOUCH** = T(he) O(ld) U(niversity) + CH (Church)
>
>  **Mean** queen following Penny (6)
>    — **CENTER** = CENT (Penny) + ER (Elizabeth Regina)
>
>  **Floating** motion around two different motorways (8)
>    — **SWIMMING** = M + MI (two motorways) in SWI.NG

The Clues – Group 2

> **Youthful** graduate at hand (4)
>    — **BABY** = B.A. (graduate) + BY (at hand)
>
>  Wandering nomad meets unknown from **beginning of week** (6)
>    — **MONDAY** = NOMAD* ("wandering") + Y (typical unknown in algebra)
>
>  **Crowds** in somber assembly back peacekeepers instead of nothing (7)
>    — **NUMBERS** = S(O > UN)MBER* ("assembly"; the UN are the peacekeepers)
>
>  **Lower** poles around distant, enclosing gas (8)
>    — **SOUTHERN** = H (hydrogen, "gas") in OUT.ER ("distant"  ), all in S.N ("poles")
>
>  Sour, ripe bananas from **manager** (8)
>    — **SUPERIOR** = (SOUR RIPE)* ("bananas")

The property all words share:

> They are all one item in a set of five:
>
>  Five fingers on a hand: Thumb, index, middle, **ring** and little finger
>  Five groups of food: **fruit**, vegetables, grains, protein and dairy
>  The five senses: sight, hearing, smell, **touch** and taste.
>  Five basketball positions: **center**, power forward, small forward, point guard and shooting guard.
>  Modern pentathlon: fencing, **swimming**, show jumping, pistol shooting and cross-country running
>
>  Five Spice Girls: Scary Spice, Sporty Spice, **Baby** Spice, Ginger Spice and Posh Spice
>  Five workdays: **Monday**, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
>  Five Books of Moses: Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, **Numbers** and Deuteronomy
>  Five Oceans: Atlantic Ocean, Pacific Ocean, Indian Ocean, Arctic Ocean and **Southern** Ocean.
>  Five Great Lakes: Lake **Superior**, Lake Michigan, Lake Huron, Lake Erie and Lake Ontario

What differs between the two groups:

> The items in Group 2 are proper names and the items in Group 1 are just regular nouns.

High fives to:

> hexomino, who solved 2.4.

Comment: My own guess for 2.4 was rot13(FBHGUREA = F naq A fheebhaqvat BHGRE juvpu pbagnvaf U (ulqebtra)) but I can't think how that would fit now.

Comment: Actually it's probably to do with rot13(gur svir cevapvcny bprnaf)

Comment: Ah, the answer makes sense. Perhaps it's rot13(gur Svir Pbzsbegf). `:)`

Comment: You got it! For 1.2, I was going for rot13(sevggref, n flabalz sbe gur ireo gevsyrf, unys bs juvpu tvirf sevg)

Comment: @hexomino Yup, you got it on both accounts!

Comment: (I guess I'm lucky that my solution worked. I'd never have gotten that synonym.)